# Read special characters and fonts from PDF using Python

Tags: python-2.7, tabula

I've a PDF in which certain table rows contain special characters and fonts 
[for e.g.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rik19.png). Is there any way to read those properly.

```
from tabula import read_pdf

df = read_pdf("Tables PDF.pdf", pages = '5', lattice = True, multiple_tables = True, encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
```

I've tried several types of encodings `utf-8`, `ascii`, `utf-8-sig`, `ISO-8859-1`. Let me know if there is any other way out.

Also tried reading one of the value separately and make the changes, by using:

```
df1.iloc[3, 6] = df1.iloc[3, 6].encode("utf-8", "replace")
```

Didn't work out. Any help will be appreciated.